# Removing all loaded definitions and constants

Tags: ruby

I have a ruby script that takes `plugin1.rb` and loads it. Then I will call `run` and `plugin1` will do its thing.

Afterwards, I might decide to load `plugin2.rb` and then call `run`, and have `plugin2` do its thing.

The two plugins have nothing to do with each other aside from the fact that it provides a `run` method for me to actually execute them, but they can define their classes and constants however they want.

There is no reason why there couldn't be class conflicts and whatnot, so I believe that the best thing to do is to clean up after the plugin finishes running.

How should I write my ruby script so that before it actually loads one of the plugins, it will properly clean up anything from a previous session so that it's ready for the new script?

I want to know what kinds of things I need to remove, and how to remove them.

UPDATE

Looking around, I can get a list of constants defined using `Object.constants`, which includes all of the classes and modules that have been loaded.

So I'm thinking of something on the lines of

```
# get start-up constants
initial_consts = Object.constants

# load a plugin
load "plugin1.rb"

# get new constants
new_consts = Object.constants - initial_consts

# run plugin
test = NewClass.new #defined in plugin
test.run

# clean-up new things
new_consts.each {|c| Object.send(:remove_const, c) }
```

This doesn't "revert" any classes that were changed, but my design prevents plugins from defining classes or methods with certain names, so it shouldn't be too big an issue.

Comment: I think you should not try to do this. Every library should define classes under some distinctively named module as a namespace so there is little chance of a collision. This is why gems don't all tend to step on each other.

Answer (score 2):

NO, No, no. This is *terrible*. For starters, it's **WRONG** to try to write code today with the goal of accepting *complete shit* code tomorrow. You can write code that is easier to understand, that is somewhat clever, and that is extensible, but don't get caught trying to write code that is supposed to be smarter than the next developer.

Now please, go back to the drawing board. Forget everything you know about what a "plugin" is, and everything you ever learned about PHP or C or other less-dynamic languages. What are your needs? How can you address them in a way that works today, and can be extended tomorrow? Do that, and *not a damn thing more*. Are you going to write code using the global namespace for all of your classes, or are you going to encapsulate them in a module named after the library to prevent this?

There are all sorts of tools available to you to lock down an environment, such as Clean Rooms, but I don't think you even need any of this. I think you really just need to quit trying to write code for ambiguous needs with the ambitious goal of handling every possibility.

Comment: The main issue with each plugin is the fact that there is data  serialized using Marshal that each plugin is reading, but the data itself assumes a global namespace and thus when they are loaded using Marshal, they pretty much assume all of the classes are in global namespace. I could be reading in data from two different files with the exact same class names, but completely different class hierarchies, signatures, instance variables, and constants. Each plugin defines the classes to correctly read the correct data. I have no control over how the input is designed.